# How to change a loop function to a recursive function using MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

The program I coded prompts the user for an integer value reads that value in and finds the largest power of 2 that is equal to or smaller than the value entered by the user. For example, the user inputs 40 and the output would be 5. I have this loop function but I want to write it recursively and get the same result. This is the code snippet of the function:

```
.ent largest
largest:
        addi $sp, $sp, -4
        sw $ra, 0($sp)
        addi $t0, $a0, 0  # place the number passed in as parameter into $t0
        li $t1, 1        # load 2^0 into $t1
        li $t2, 0        # load 0 into $t2
        loop: bgt $t1, $t0, done   # if 2^n is larger than $t0, done, return n-1
        mul $t1, $t1, 2
        addi $t2, $t2, 1
        b loop
    done:
        addi $a0, $t2, -1 # return n-1
        lw $ra, 0($sp)
        addiu $sp, $sp, 4
        jr $ra            # return from main method
.end largest
```

I really can't figure it out. If anyone can help me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: try same in C, it'll be easier to do in assembly once you do that.

Comment: AS you can see on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/HDNtcc), there isn't actually a real difference between iterative and (tail-)recursive code for a reasonable compiler.